An algebraic structure with N5 as a congruence lattice
A while ago I tried and failed to produce a finite structure with this as its congruence lattice by enumerating random structures with a computer program and computing their congruence lattices.
Later, I tried to produce a structure with $N_5$ as its representation lattice, but I learned a few years later that this approach was also incorrect.
What is an example of an algebraic structure with $N_5$ as its congruence lattice?
Here is an ASCII Hasse diagram of $N_5$ for reference:
        1
      /  \
      a   c
      |   |
      |   b
      |  /
        0 
        
```


I don't understand how that's different from this question to which you provided an answer, and William DeMeo had already provided one. Am I missing something or did you just forget?

I just forgot. never mind.
